# why RDLC report pick some value in group of two column if column one value is null

Tags: rdlc

As shown in below image i have created two column group one for value one for %age, the problem i am facing is that, if cell value of value column is null and i try to get that cell value in %age column it give me some other rows cell value that is not null in the desired cell but it should give null there.

[image: RDLC null value is not evaluated correctly]

Need help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its strang
When i was using Expression

> =Fields!AccountBalances.Value

it give the above Error

But when i used

> =SUM(Fields!AccountBalances.value)

Its resolved

Any one care to elaborate?

Hope it will help some one like me a beginner